# 1С 8.3. Как в регистр накопления добавить еще один столбец?

Tags: 1с

Как в регистр накопления добавить еще один столбец?

Вид регистра - Остатки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого откройте Форму (Регистра накопления) и добавьте колонку;
Если Формы нет, тогда в пользовательском режиме, попробуйте через ЕЩЕ - Изменить форму - Установить стандартные настройки; Колонка должна появиться;